# Azure Application Gateway return 502 Bad Gateway - Health check and network fine

Tags: azure, azure-application-gateway

I have created the Azure Application Gateway with HTTPS backend.
The problem here is the health check is showed healthily. 
But when I connect to Application Gateway it returns 502
I check directly to the backend server but it still fine. HTTP Backend works fine also, only self-signed HTTPS backend got the problem.

Do you have any idea or troubleshooting way for this?

Comment: did you configure SSL offloading on the application gateway? i dont think I've saw five hundreds on a healthy backend ever

Comment: Any update on your question?

Comment: @NancyXiong I'm not sure yet, let me try to create another self-signed cert with root cert, I just create the server cert only

Answer (score 0):

This could happen in the scenario that **AppGW v2** when the client receives 502 through the Application Gateway when the back-end is Healthy and no Request Time-Outs.

You could first check [these common scenarios](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/application-gateway-troubleshooting-502#overview), Also you could consider two cases of the health probe.

**Default Probe**:

AppGW v2 will always show the back-end as healthy when the probe used is the default. So ALWAYS verify if the back-end is really healthy.

**Custom Probe**:

In this case, the AppGW v2 is supposed to be showing the right health of the back-end.

Furthermore, Authentication Certificates have been deprecated and replaced by **Trusted Root Certificates** in the Application Gateway v2 SKU. Read more details [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/ssl-overview#end-to-end-ssl-with-the-v2-sku).

> If the certificate is self-signed, or signed by unknown
>   intermediaries, then to enable end to end SSL in v2 SKU a trusted root
>   certificate must be defined. Application Gateway will only communicate
>   with backends whose Server certificate’s root certificate matches one
>   of the list of trusted root certificates in the backend http setting
>   associated with the pool.

**Note**

> The self-signed certificate must be a part of a certificate chain. A
>   single self-signed certificate with no chain is not supported in V2
>   SKU.

You can also check if the back-end returns the complete chain of Certs to AppGW via any of the SSL Checkers Online: https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html

More references:

- [Generate an Azure Application Gateway self-signed certificate with a custom root CA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/self-signed-certificates)
- [Create certificates to allow the backend with Azure Application Gateway](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/certificates-for-backend-authentication)

Comment: If the certificate is self-signed, or signed by unknown intermediaries, then to enable end to end SSL in v2 SKU a trusted root certificate must be defined. Application Gateway will only communicate with backends whose Server certificate’s root certificate matches one of the list of trusted root certificates in the backend http setting associated with the pool. I think because of this, let me give a try on this

Comment: Hello, any update or learning from this? facing exact similar issue with self signed certificate that is installed on the back-end server but not sure what needs to be entered in the "Cert name" field while configuring the Http settings after uploading the .cer file? Please help!